# Can't get Liquibase gradle plugin to work with Spring JPA application

Tags: gradle, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

I'm trying to generate a diff change log between the existing database and our Spring JPA application. Generating the initial changeLog is successful now and for the diff, I managed to get past the class path issues (with great help of StackOverflow answers), but now I'm stuck on the diff change log.

This is the error that I get on `gradlew :dbinit:diffChangeLog`:

```
:dbinit:diffChangeLog
liquibase-plugin: Running the 'main' activity...
INFO 11/7/16 7:54 AM: liquibase-hibernate: Reading hibernate configuration hibernate:spring:nu.yona.server.subscriptions.entities?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
INFO 11/7/16 7:54 AM: liquibase-hibernate: Found package nu.yona.server.subscriptions.entities
INFO 11/7/16 7:54 AM: liquibase-hibernate: Found dialect org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL

SEVERE 11/7/16 7:54 AM: liquibase: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:127)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.createReferenceDatabaseFromCommandParams(Main.java:1283)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:996)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.run(Main.java:188)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:46)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.call(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:91)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at org.liquibase.gradle.LiquibaseTask.runLiquibase(LiquibaseTask.groovy:97)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:384)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:69)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
        at org.liquibase.gradle.LiquibaseTask$_liquibaseAction_closure1.doCall(LiquibaseTask.groovy:52)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1024)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:414)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2030)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1890)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$159.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:274)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
        at org.liquibase.gradle.LiquibaseTask.liquibaseAction(LiquibaseTask.groovy:46)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:136)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:129)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:118)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:623)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:606)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:233)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:74)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:55)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:186)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:183)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:33)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:112)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:66)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:79)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:59)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:44)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:293)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:593)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.preparePersistenceUnitInfos(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:445)
        at liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateSpringDatabase.buildConfigurationFromScanning(HibernateSpringDatabase.java:227)
        at liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateSpringDatabase.buildConfiguration(HibernateSpringDatabase.java:55)
        at liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.HibernateDatabase.setConnection(HibernateDatabase.java:46)
        at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(DatabaseFactory.java:131)
        at liquibase.database.DatabaseFactory.openDatabase(DatabaseFactory.java:151)
        at liquibase.integration.commandline.CommandLineUtils.createDatabaseObject(CommandLineUtils.java:85)
        ... 130 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:187)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:590)
        ... 137 more


For more information, use the --logLevel flag
:dbinit:diffChangeLog FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dbinit:diffChangeLog'.
> liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.522 secs
```

This is `build.gradle`:

```
description = 'Database initializer'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$project.ext.springBootVersion")
        classpath("io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:0.6.1.RELEASE")
        classpath('se.transmode.gradle:gradle-docker:1.2')
        classpath 'net.researchgate:gradle-release:2.3.4'
        classpath 'org.liquibase:liquibase-gradle-plugin:1.2.1'
        classpath("org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.3.3")
        classpath("org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate4:3.6")
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.4.1.RELEASE")
        classpath("org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:3.0.7.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'docker'
apply plugin: 'net.researchgate.release'
apply plugin: 'liquibase'

jar {
    baseName = 'DatabaseInitializer'
}

release {
    failOnCommitNeeded = true
    tagTemplate = 'adminservice-${version}'
    git {
        requireBranch = 'yd-40-changes-for-building|master'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.4.1.RELEASE")
    compile("org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:3.0.7.RELEASE")
}

group = 'yonadev'

task buildDocker(type: Docker, dependsOn: bootRepackage) {
    tag = "${project.group}/yonahsqldb"
    push = true
    applicationName = jar.baseName
    dockerfile = file('src/main/docker/Dockerfile')
    doFirst {
        copy {
            from bootRepackage
            into stageDir
            rename "${jar.baseName}-${jar.version}-${bootRepackage.classifier}", "${jar.baseName}"
        }
        copy {
            from 'data'
            into "$stageDir/data"
        }
    }
}

bootRun {
    enableAssertions=true

    systemProperties = [
        'spring.datasource.url': "jdbc:hsqldb:file:../YonaDB",
        'spring.batch.initializer.enabled': "true",
        'spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto': "update"
    ]
}

bootRepackage {
        classifier = "full"
}

liquibase {
    activities {
        main {
            changeLogFile 'changelog.groovy'
            url 'jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://yonadbserver/xdb'
            referenceUrl 'hibernate:spring:nu.yona.server.subscriptions.entities?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect'
            username 'sa'
            password ''
            changeLogParameters([ myToken: 'myvalue',
                            second: 'secondValue'])
        }
    }

    // runList = project.ext.runList
    runList = 'main'
}
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have run `gradle clean` or won't compile ur **project java** file before
If you read your **Exception** carefully, definitely you will able to resolve your problem.

As i can see your **Exception** hierarchy its something like this

```
liquibase: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
```

It means your compiled classes are not available on your classpath, and liquibase only scan into your classpath.

> Now if you see your stacktrace at bottom it clearly throws `FileNotFoundException` it means there is no class available at classpath

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

So, Now come to the solution which is u need to compile all ur class before using `diff` then liquibase found the class on classpath and compare with database then generate the changelog and append it into ur `diffChangeLog` file.
:)

please run `gradle compile` just before generating `diff` against your java Class

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm. I am using `maven` instead of `gradle` and I had to run `mvn clean` and `mvn install` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to ignore the Liquibase Gradle plug-in and go with a custom Gradle task [as described by here Hazim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35721103/4353482). That works like a charm.