# How to use liquibase to generate a changelog from diffs between a database and persistence entities in spring?

Tags: spring, hibernate, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

Please i need solution to the above question in spring (JAVA based config) and NOT in spring boot.
Most of the tutorials i found online are based on spring boot but my app is not running on spring boot, 
just spring mvc.
I have the necessary dependencies already in my classpath, that's liquibase-core-3.5.3 and liquibase-hibernate5-3.6 jars.

I have also created liquibase properties file (in classpath too) as shown below

```
driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
changeLogFile=classpath:db-changelog.xml
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase
username=myusername
password=mypassword
referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:com.mypackage.entity?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
diffChangeLogFile=com/mypackage/dbchangelog/diff-changelog.xml
```

The problem now is how do i execute it to generate a diff changelog file?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to do it using liquibase plugin for maven or gradle depending on what you use for build.

[Maven plugin](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/) as very good documentation as to how you can run liquibase commands.

If you are using gradle, liquibase plugin doesn't work smoothly when calling `diffChangeLog`.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35716378/unable-to-generate-difference-from-liquibase-gradle-plugin/35721103#35721103), create a file named `liquibase.gradle`. I have edited some properties as per `hibernate5` since it doesn't support `ImprovedNamingStrategy` anymore.

```
def diffLog = "$projectDir/src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog.yaml"

configurations {
    liquibase
}

dependencies {
    liquibase 'org.liquibase.ext:liquibase-hibernate5:3.6'
}

task liquibaseDiffChangelog(type: JavaExec) {
    group = "liquibase"

    classpath sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    classpath configurations.liquibase
    main = "liquibase.integration.commandline.Main"

    args "--changeLogFile=" + diffLog
    args "--referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:com.mypackage.entity?hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"
    args "--username=<username>"
    args "--password=<password>"
    args "--url=jdbc:mysql://<db_host_and_port>/<db_name>"
    args "--referenceDriver=liquibase.ext.hibernate.database.connection.HibernateDriver"
    args "diffChangeLog"
}
```

Add `apply from: 'liquibase.gradle'` in your `build.gradle`.

Now, to generate diffChangeLog, invoke `gradle liquibaseDiffChangelog`.

Please note the example uses one of spring boot's class as Hibernate Physical Naming Strategy. You can create your own implementation by referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437202/improvednamingstrategy-no-longer-working-in-hibernate-5/34565182#34565182).

Answer (score 0):

here is spring bean config :

```
@Bean
public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
    SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
    liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:db-changelog.xml");
    liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource());
    return liquibase;
}
```

and xml config from [liquibase - web site][1]

```
<bean id="liquibase" class="liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase">
      <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
      <property name="changeLog" value="classpath:db-changelog.xml" />

      <!--
      contexts specifies the runtime contexts to use.
      -->
      <property name="contexts" value="test, production" />
```

from source : **SpringLiquibase** -- it's code execute update , it's default behaviour .

```
protected void performUpdate(Liquibase liquibase) throws LiquibaseException{
    if (tag != null) {
        liquibase.update(tag, new Contexts(getContexts()), new LabelExpression(getLabels()));
    } else {
        liquibase.update(new Contexts(getContexts()), new LabelExpression(getLabels()));
    }
}
```

class Liquibase has method

> ```
> public DiffResult diff(Database referenceDatabase,
>                        Database targetDatabase, 
>                        CompareControl compareControl)
> ```

so , you can create custom SpringLiquibase  and use diff instead of update

```
public class MyDiffSpringLiquibase extends SpringLiquibase {

    @Override
    protected void performUpdate(Liquibase liquibase) throws LiquibaseException {
    Database referenceDatabase = new MySQLDatabase();
    referenceDatabase.setConnection();

    Database targetDatabase = new MySQLDatabase();
    targetDatabase.setConnection();

    CatalogAndSchema catalogAndSchemaReference = new CatalogAndSchema();
    CatalogAndSchema catalogAndSchemacomparison = new CatalogAndSchema();

    Set<Class<? extends DatabaseObject>> finalCompareTypes = null;
    Class<? extends DatabaseObject>[] snapshotTypes = new Class[]{Table.class ,View.class......};
    if (snapshotTypes != null && snapshotTypes.length > 0) {
        finalCompareTypes = new HashSet<Class<? extends DatabaseObject>>(Arrays.asList(snapshotTypes));
    }

    CompareControl compareControl = new CompareControl(new CompareControl.SchemaComparison[]{new CompareControl.SchemaComparison(catalogAndSchemaReference, catalogAndSchemacomparison)}, finalCompareTypes);
    liquibase.diff(referenceDatabase, targetDatabase, compareControl);
    }
}
```

and register it as bean

```
@Bean
public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
    SpringLiquibase liquibase = new MyDiffSpringLiquibase ();
    liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:db-changelog.xml");
    liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource());
    return liquibase;
}
```

Comment: This is not what I want. I know this already. Please understand my question. What i need is how to generate a changelog from differences between a database and persistence entities?